# Python strip() multiple characters?

Tags: python

I want to remove any brackets from a string. Why doesn't this work properly?

```
>>> name = "Barack (of Washington)"
>>> name = name.strip("(){}<>")
>>> print name
Barack (of Washington
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I did a time test here, using each method 100000 times in a loop.  The results surprised me.  (The results still surprise me after editing them in response to valid criticism in the comments.)

Here's the script:

```
import timeit

bad_chars = '(){}<>'

setup = """import re
import string
s = 'Barack (of Washington)'
bad_chars = '(){}<>'
rgx = re.compile('[%s]' % bad_chars)"""

timer = timeit.Timer('o = "".join(c for c in s if c not in bad_chars)', setup=setup)
print "List comprehension: ",  timer.timeit(100000)


timer = timeit.Timer("o= rgx.sub('', s)", setup=setup)
print "Regular expression: ", timer.timeit(100000)

timer = timeit.Timer('for c in bad_chars: s = s.replace(c, "")', setup=setup)
print "Replace in loop: ", timer.timeit(100000)

timer = timeit.Timer('s.translate(string.maketrans("", "", ), bad_chars)', setup=setup)
print "string.translate: ", timer.timeit(100000)
```

Here are the results:

```
List comprehension:  0.631745100021
Regular expression:  0.155561923981
Replace in loop:  0.235936164856
string.translate:  0.0965719223022
```

Results on other runs follow a similar pattern.  If speed is not the primary concern, however, I still think `string.translate` is not the most readable; the other three are more obvious, though slower to varying degrees.

Comment: thanks for this - educative question, not only did I learn that strip() doesn't do what I thought, I also learned three other ways to achieve what I wanted, and which was the fastest!

Comment: wont work for unicode: translate() only takes one argument (table) with unicode.

Comment: minus 1: For making something about speed which should be about code clarity and robustness.

Comment: @jwg , you're totally right; looking back at this, it's an exercise in high-visibility missing of the point.  Somehow, though, it keeps getting upvotes.  (I did learn some interesting things about using timeit, though.)

Answer (score 123):

Because that's not what `strip()` does. It removes leading and trailing characters that are present in the argument, but not those characters in the middle of the string.

You could do:

```
name= name.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace ...
```

or:

```
name= ''.join(c for c in name if c not in '(){}<>')
```

or maybe use a regex:

```
import re
name= re.sub('[(){}<>]', '', name)
```

Answer (score 17):

[string.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) with table=None works fine.

```
>>> name = "Barack (of Washington)"
>>> name = name.translate(None, "(){}<>")
>>> print name
Barack of Washington
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Python 3 for strings, only for bytes and bytearray.

Answer (score 16):

Because `strip()` only strips trailing and leading characters, based on what you provided. I suggest:

```
>>> import re
>>> name = "Barack (of Washington)"
>>> name = re.sub('[\(\)\{\}<>]', '', name)
>>> print(name)
Barack of Washington
```

Comment: In a regex character class you don't need to escape anything, so '[(){}<>]' is fine

Answer (score 10):

`strip` only strips characters from the very front and back of the string.

To delete a list of characters, you could use the string's `translate` method:

```
import string
name = "Barack (of Washington)"
table = string.maketrans( '', '', )
print name.translate(table,"(){}<>")
# Barack of Washington
```

Answer (score 0):

Since strip only removes characters from start and end, one idea could be to break the string into list of words, then remove chars, and then join:

```
s = 'Barack (of Washington)'
x = [j.strip('(){}<>') for j in s.split()]
ans = ' '.join(j for j in x)
print(ans)
```

Answer (score -4):

For example string `s="(U+007c)"`

To remove only the parentheses from s, try the below one:

```
import re
a=re.sub("\\(","",s)
b=re.sub("\\)","",a)
print(b)
```

Comment: How does that remove parenthesis? By removing anything that isn't alphanumeric?

Comment: When the question says "remove parenthesis" but your answer says "removing anything that's not alphanumeric", I don't think you're addressing the question.