# How to extract some specific special character from input value using python

Tags: python, django

I need some help. I need to escape some specific special character like `semicolon, pipe, redirection and ampersand` from input string which is got by post method using python and Django. I am explaining my code below.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   rname = request.POST.get('react')
```

Here from the above input value I need to remove the special character. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
import string
bad_chars = "()|&"
rname = "|icha()"
rname.translate(string.maketrans("", "", ), bad_chars)

# This becomes 'icha'
```

This is explained in [Python strip() multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900054/python-strip-multiple-characters)

Comment: here where is my input string ?

Comment: rname is your input string

Comment: you have assigned `"|icha()"` to rname.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with regular expressions. My approach would be:

```
import re

special_chars = r'[;\|>&]'
rname = request.POST.get('react')
cleaned_rname = re.sub(special_chars, '', rname)
```

Now if the string `rname` contains any of the special characters they will be removed and you'll get a new string `cleaned_rname` with the output.

In the variable `special_chars` you can specify all characters that should be removed. They are enclosed within square brackets: `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Please state clearly which variable to escape from which characters and what they shall become.

A snippet that may help you:

```
>>> 'HeRllo'.replace('R','')
Hello
```

Or, for a given list of characters:

```
>>> stringToEscape = 'He&ll;o'
>>> sources = ['&', ';']
>>> targets = ['', '']
>>> for source, target in zip(sources, targets):
>>>   stringToEscape = stringToEscape.replace(source, target)
>>> print stringToEscape
Hello
```

But maybe you are looking for a special function that already exists in `Django`.

Answer (score 0):

This uses replace method:

```
chars = ";>" # and so on
rname = "stuff;"

for char in chars:
    if char in rname:
        new_rname = rname.replace(char,'')
    rname = new_rname
```

You have to assign to a new variable because strings are immutable. Result should be:

```
>>print(rname)
stuff
```